# Should the [handicap], [handicapping], and [odds] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [handicapping](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handicapping) tag says:

> Questions related to handicapping a player in chess

The [handicap](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handicap) tag says:

> Games with handicap to compensate for difference in playing strength. For instance "pawn and move" odds means the stronger player is black (move) and has f7 pawn removed (pawn) before the start of the game. "Rook" odds usually means the stronger player is white and has his a1 rook removed before the start of the game.These used to be common 100 years ago usually combined with gambling on the result but are much rarer today.

The [odds](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odds) tag says:

> For questions about games where odds have been given or about giving odds usually to handicap the stronger player. e.g. "pawn and move odds" means the stronger player is black and has the f7 pawn removed before play starts, "knight odds" means the stronger player is white and has the b1 knight removed before play starts.

Should these be merged, perhaps making the ones that are removed synonyms instead? I don't see any difference between them.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Handicapping can also involve giving different amounts of time to the two players.

Comment: And "odds" does not? I know I've at least heard the phrase "time odds".

Comment: But on reflection, I think you are correct. Odds may be given even if the intent is not to handicap; for example, an Armageddon game may give time odds *and* draw odds, but the intent is to have a fair game, not to handicap the stronger player.

Comment: In that case we should create tags names "time-handicap" and "material-handicap" rather than having two overlapping ones